# Proving tan((x + y)/2) = (sin x + sin y)/(cos x + cos y) with the angle sum and difference identities

Tags: trigonometry

I've recently come across this problem of proving

$$ \tan \frac{x + y}{2} = \frac{\sin x + \sin y}{\cos x + \cos y} $$

Not a difficult problem, I thought. I would have rewritten the RHS using the sum-to-product identities of sine and cosine.

But the solution given in the back of the book is

\begin{align}
\tan \frac{x + y}{2} &= \frac{\sin x \sin y}{\cos x + \cos y} \\
&= \frac{2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})+2\sin(\frac{y}{2})\cos(\frac{y}{2})}{2\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})-1 + 1 - 2\sin^2(\frac{y}{2})} \\
&= \frac{\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2}) + \sin(\frac{y}{2})\cos(\frac{y}{2})}{\cos^2(\frac{x}{2}) - \sin^2(\frac{y}{2})} \tag{1} \\
&= \frac{\sin(\frac{x+y}{2})}{\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})}  \tag{2} \\
&= \tan \frac{x + y}{2}
\end{align}

What I'm confused about is the step from (1) to (2). It appears they tried to use the angle sum identities, but Wikipedia says that the formulas are actually

$$ \sin(\alpha \pm \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta \pm \cos \alpha \sin \beta \\
\cos(\alpha \pm \beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta \mp \sin \alpha \sin \beta
$$

which don't actually match the numerator or denominator in (1). Can the angle sum identities be used like this?

I'm also interested in knowing how one would *actually* go from (1) to (2) without the angle sum identities. It seems like there would be a few intermediate steps.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: It definitely looks wrong to say $\cos^2(x/2)-\sin^2(y/2)=\cos((x+y)/2)$. Same for the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the formulae that express the trigonometric functions  in function of the tangent of the half-angle. So set $\;t=\tan\dfrac x2,\enspace u=\tan y2$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin x+\sin y}{\cos x+\cos y}&=\frac{\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}+\dfrac{2u}{1+u^2}}{\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}+\dfrac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}=\frac{2\bigl(t(1+u^2)+u(1+t^2)\bigr)}{(1-t^2)(1+u^2)+(1-u^2)(1+t^2)}\\
&=\dfrac{2(t+u)(1+tu)}{2(1-t^2u^2)}=\frac{t+u}{1-tu}= \tan\Bigl(\frac x2+\frac y2\Bigr).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   \frac{\sin x + \sin y}{\cos x + \cos y}
   &= \frac{\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2} + \frac{x-y}{2}\right)
      +     \sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2} - \frac{x-y}{2}\right)}
           {\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2} + \frac{x-y}{2}\right)
      +     \cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2} - \frac{x-y}{2}\right)}\\
   &= \frac{2\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)}
           {2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)}\\
   &= \tan\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)
\end{align}